# SocketException:Connection reset on every request + Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I see the below line application log.

ERROR [TcpNetConnection.java:263] Read exception rclegacy-dev.kkl.com:9103:48416:1a40a36a-8cb6-4a2a-9229-ae4fe5273966 SocketException:Connection reset

There are no issues with the request-response flows. But I see the above line in the logs every time a request is sent and received. I have implemented Spring integration for the TCP communication and using a AbstractByteArraySerializer for Custom (De)Serialiazation. How can I get rid of this error?

Here is my SI configuration.

```
<int:gateway id="gw" service-interface=" com.api.MyGateway"
        default-request-channel="objectOut" />

    <int:channel id="objectOut" />

    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
        type="client" host="#{configProperties.limitKeyMap['host']}"  port="#{configProperties.limitKeyMap['port']}" single-use="false"     so-timeout="50000000" using-nio="false" so-keep-alive="true"
        serializer="customDSerializer" deserializer="customDSerializer" />
    <bean id="customDSerializer" class="CustomSerializerDeserializer">
        <property name="maxMessageSize" value="4096" />
    </bean>

    <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
        request-channel="objectOut" reply-channel="toSA" connection-factory="client"
        request-timeout="100000" reply-timeout="50000"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
        ref="myService" method="parseResponse"/>

    <bean id="myService" class="com.api.services.MyService"/>

    <int:channel id="toSA" />
    <int:channel id="bytesIn" />
```

CustomDeserializer

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.AbstractByteArraySerializer;


public class CustomSerializerDeserializer extends AbstractByteArraySerializer {


    
    Logger streamLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomSerializerDeserializer.class);

    public CustomSerializerDeserializer() {
    }
    
    @Override
    public void serialize(byte[] bytes, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    
        int length = bytes.length;
        outputStream.write(bytes); 
    }
    
    @Override
    public byte[] deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        byte[] messageBuffer = null;
        messageBuffer = new byte[2400];
        int bytesRead = read(inputStream, messageBuffer, false);
        return messageBuffer;
    }
    
    protected int read(InputStream inputStream, byte[] buffer, boolean header)
            throws IOException {
        
        int lengthRead = 0;
        int dataLength = buffer.length;
        while (lengthRead < dataLength) {
            
            int len;
            len = inputStream.read(buffer, lengthRead,
                    dataLength - lengthRead);
            if (len < 0 && header && lengthRead == 0) {
                streamLogger.debug("[read] length<0 ? {}", len);
                return len;
            }
            if (len < 0) {
                throw new IOException("Stream closed after " + lengthRead + " of " + dataLength);
            }
            lengthRead += len;
            if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            }
        }
        return lengthRead;
        
    }
    
}
```

Stacktrace example

```
04/08 22:06:50:794  INFO [MyService.java:492] Amt|0.0|
04/08 22:06:50:797  ERROR [TcpNetConnection.java:263] Read exception testlegacy-cert.pip.com:9000:46506:3fdd2dff-5bcd-48bc-b6ca-cb03c1277a65 SocketException:Connection reset
04/08 22:06:50:802  INFO [MyService.java:500] Date |Wed Apr 08 22:06:00 CDT 2020|
```

Error got printed in between parsing the TCP response. No other errors or exceptions. Request and response works fine.

Comment: #1 show, please, more stack trace. #2 what are your (de)serializer?

Comment: @ArtemBilan There is no stacktrace  except the line mentioned. The only line with ERROR level is this. And I could see it every time the response is received from the server. Updated question with deserializer class. In fact, I implemented it per your suggestion

Comment: @ArtemBilan Added a sample from the log. Not sure if that would help

Comment: Set `single-use="true"`. You have explicitly set it to false and the close is considered an error.

Comment: @GaryRussell Okay. Let me try that and come back to you.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the server is closing the socket after sending the reply; that is considered an error on the client side, unless you set `single-use` to `true` on the client connection factory.